# A java applet (on Unix) opens an Abiword file: How can I determinate the PID of this open file?

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, applet

When my applet opens the text file, I see in the terminal (with command ps -ef) many processes and 2 are of my interest:

1- is about the Java process (/usr/lib/jvm/.....) 
2- is about my abiword opened file.

I found in stackoverflow how get the PID of Java process, but I'm interested on the PID of Abiword process (second point).

I need it to understand (under Unix) if user, after a save, closed or not the document. (I know that the method renameTo() on Unix doesn't work)

If you know another better way to work around it....well...I'll appreciate it!

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Got any code you could share? Without knowing *how* Java is launching Abiword, I don't think I could hazard a guess. Also, I'm afraid I don't see how knowing the PID will help with your ultimate goal.

Comment: @dcsohl My goal is to find this PID of the opened document and, when the user click on Save button, I lunch this other command: " lsof | grep write "  to see if the PID upon is in this list. If yes it implicates that user doesn't closed the document. This is what I thought.... It is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for answering my second question. How about the first one? Also, to know a "better way to work around it", I suppose we should understand why you need to know if they've closed the document, lest we [start shaving yaks](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html)